# Can I have inputs without forms in a Rails view?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller

I want to have a few check boxes on my page, and a link that accesses the value of these check boxes to pass in a `link_to` helper. I did not want to use a form because the view essentially has a number of links interspersed, and it doesn't naturally seem to be a form with one logical submit button.

I have something like

```
 <% for p in @some_array %>
 <!--other stuff .... -->
 <input value=<%= p.id %> id=<%= p.id %> name="selected[]" type=checkbox>
 <!--other stuff .... -->
<%= link_to "View all selected thing(s)", :action => 'show_selected', :selected_things => selected[] %>
```

But it doesn't seem to recognize the variable `selected` which stores the inputs. It raises

```
undefined local variable or method `selected' for #<#<Class:0x000001021b4a38>:0x00000102319a90>
```

Comment: You're mixing Ruby (server side, `<%= link_to ... %>`) with stuff on the client side (browser, the form, and form elements with name `selected[]`). There is no direct connection without you making one, or framework magic.

Comment: I guess that's my question - may be I didn't explain myself clearly. How do I make such a connection if I want to use the inputs from some html element to send to a server side method, other than using a form submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the last line in your code snippet is causing the error:

```
<%= link_to "View all selected thing(s)", :action => 'show_selected', :selected_things => selected[] %>
```

As ruby complains about a `selected` not being defined.

(Although I can't see why you don't want to use a form, as forcing the selections into something you can pass to the link would require some javascript magic.)

Comment: Thanks. I know the error comes from this line. How do I define a variable to use for the input from checkboxes? Is it possible to use the inputs in a link_to without using a form?

Comment: as I said, you would need some javascript to react to the checkboxes, collect something and build a request out of it (which makes this a javascript question, no rails involved here) but why on earth do you want to do it without a form?

Comment: Got it. The links are built statically, and the value of the input boxes can't change their values.